# Validation Loss Never Decreases

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a neural network for regression with TensorFlow, and getting strange behaviour on my loss curves. The task is to predict the motion of an object in an image, when an action is applied to the object. So the network takes in an image, and an action, and outputs the motion.

The image input is followed by three CNN layers, and in parallel, the action input is followed by a dense layer. These are then concatenated, and followed by two dense layers, before the output. All layers have ReLUs. Data is normalised to have zero mean and standard deviation of one.

Below is the training curve:

[image]

The strange behaviour is that, whilst the training loss decreases over time, the validation loss increases right from the start. Usually, when the training curve decreases far below the validation curve, this indicates overfitting. However, in my case, the validation curve never actually decreases at all. Usually, overfitting can be diagnosed when the validation curve drops and then rises again.

Instead, it is as if the network is overfitting right from the very first epoch. In fact, the validation curve seems to follow the opposite trajectory to the training curve. Every improvement in the training prediction results in an opposite effect on the validation prediction.

I have also tried varying the step size (I am using Adam, and in this graph, the step size is 0.0001, then reduces to 0.00001 at epoch 100). My network uses dropout on all the dense layers. I have also tried reducing the number of parameters in the network to prevent overfitting, but the same behaviour occurs. I have a batch size of 50.

**What could be the diagnosis of this behaviour**? Is the network overfitting, or something else? If it is overfitting, then why do my attempts to reduce the number of parameters and add dropout still result in this same effect? Andy why does the overfitting occur immediately, without the validation loss decreasing at all?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your model look like. 3 separate single layer convolutional layers whose output is concactenated? Are you doing any data preprocessing?

Comment: There are two inputs: the image and action. The image data goes threough three CNN layers, ab in parallels, the action data goes through a dense layer. These are then concatenated and followed by two dense layers to predict the motion. However, I have played around with bigger or smaller networks, and get a similar learning curve.

Comment: The data is preprocessed to have zero mean and standard deviation of 1.